# Service function returning empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I've got a factory function that won't return a variable I'm trying to set in my controller. I don't get an error though, just the variable won't get set to what it's suppose to.

```
spApp.factory('SiteService', function ($q){
    var rootUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
    var siteMap;

    //returns object containing info about all sites within collection
    var getSiteMap = function () {
        siteMap = {};

        var promise = $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
            async: true
        });

        promise.then(
            function (response){
                map = {}; //init the map
                var web = $(response).find("Web").map(function () {
                    return $(this).attr('Url');
                });
                var webTitle = $(response).find("Web").map(function () {
                    return $(this).attr('Title');
                });  

                // create map
                for (var i = 0; i < web.length; i++) {
                    var item = web[i],
                        title = webTitle[i],
                        parts = item.split('/'),
                        domain = parts.splice(0, 3).join('/'),
                        current;

                    if (!map[domain]) map[domain] = {url:domain, title:title ,children:{}};
                    current = map[domain].children;

                    for (var index in parts) {
                        var part = parts[index];
                        if (!current[part]) {
                            current[part] = {url:domain+'/'+parts.slice(0,index+1).join('/'), title:title, children:{}};
                        }
                        current = current[part].children;
                    }
                }
            siteMap = map;
        }, function(reason){
            alert('FAILED:' + reason);
        })
        console.log(siteMap);
        return siteMap;
    }

    return{
        getSiteMap:getSiteMap
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are checking your variable before the promise has been resolved.

Comment: I tried putting the return in the .then function but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chaining your promises like this:

```
var getSiteMap = function () {
    siteMap = {};

    var promise = $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
        async: true
    });

     return promise.then(function(response){ //return your promise
        // all you code
        siteMap = map;

        return siteMap; //return a value to another .then in the chain
    });
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
SiteService.getSiteMap().then(function(siteMap){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you are working with promises. When you put your `console.log` outside your `then()` function, you are logging the variable *before* it has actually been resolved.

If you put your `console.log` inside your `then()` function (after sitemap is assigned), it should show the correct value, but you still won't be able to access it reliably.

I think the simplest way for you to access the `siteMap` value *after* it has been populated with data is to pass in a callback function. Eg:

```
var getSiteMap = function (_callback) {
    siteMap = {};

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
        async: true
    }).then(function(response){
        // Process the data and set siteMap
        // ...
        siteMap = map;

        // now pass siteMap to the callback
        _callback(siteMap);
    });
```

You would then use this in your controller like so:

```
SiteService.getSiteMap(function(sitemap){
    // Do something with your sitemap here
});
```

Now while this will work, it is just one quick example, and not necessarily the best way. If you don't like callbacks, you could create a second promise that resolves only when `siteMap` is assigned. Also depending on your use case for `getSiteMap()`, you may want to cache the value, otherwise the request will be called every time.